# Is it possible to create table in sqlite database of already installed android application without reinstalling or clearing the data of application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have done such thing only either reinstalling the application or clearing applications data.Is there any way to do it without actually clearing data or reinstalling the Application?
I am new to Android Development.

Comment: That depends on what your code is currently doing. Are you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: Yes I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: The `SQLiteOpenHelper` class can manage database creation and version management for your. Did you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create such table using SQL srcipt for exmaple. You have to run it from code. Don't forget to check if table already exists. Otherwise you can receive exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create new table by running SQLite query of create table. But to do this you have to update database once.